# Increase Joomla 3 responsive menu collapse point using only CSS

Tags: joomla, menu, responsive-design, joomla3.4

I built a Joomla 3.4.3 custom template using only standard CSS, no LESS or SASS or custom javascript.

My menu has quite a few items and thus the last items overflow to a second line long before the standard collapse point of around 980px.

Is it possible to use standard CSS to increase the collapse point to 1310px?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you are using the Joomla Bootstrap instance or are you creating everything? Also it's not a big deal to insert your regular css using LESS, I would really suggest that.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using the Joomla default Bootstrap libraries.  I do not want to change Joomla core files, in case the client updates Joomla, overrides will have to be done in the template folder. If it is easier to do it using LESS then I would do it that way, thing is I would then need step by step instructions on how to incorporate LESS into Joomla and how to make the necessary changes - I have no experience with LESS.

Comment: It is much much easier to do with LESS. You just make a separate file called like "template.less" and but your custom css there. Then include that as the last less file loaded.  Then just click the compile button and it will generate the css. And if there is a syntax error in the css it won't complie so you fix it right away.  LESS is just a a superset of CSS, it has extra things but you don't need to use them. Protostar is a pretty good example if you copy that LESS file you can edit it or just add to the bottom. `@import "template.less"; // Custom for this template`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback.  If I understand correctly: 1. create new "template.less" and put all custom css there. 2. Include as last less file loaded (where do I do this - is it done in the same way as any css file within the head tags?) 3. The click compile (where do I click compile?) 4. add @import "template.less"; // Custom for this template (should I add this to my new "template.less" file at the bottom?).

Comment: Actually if you don't have a templates.less already just create it with your css, noting to add.  Take a look at protostar to see how it works. THe name doesn't matter, it should be the same name as the css file that you want.

Comment: Ok, I have created less folder within my templates folder. Inside the less folder I created blank styles.less. I then copied all content from styles.css to newly created styles.less. Then I linked to the styles.less in my index.php. I then removed the css folder because now my template should only use the .less file for its styles. Now no styles are working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NO you do not link to styles.less. You go to the template manager and click the compile button to compile the LESS into css.